# Replacing "0"s with blank cells after running formula vba

Tags: vba

Attached is a screenshot but I want to replace 0's with a blank text after I run the Min formula in my vba macro. Currently, I have done

```
For Each cell In Range("D4:D400")
If cell.Value = "0" Then cell.Clear
Next
```

and this has cleared out every single value in the column.

[image: Data Sample]

[EDIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skvtC.png)

```
Cells(PoleRow, 4).Formula = "=MIN($AK$" & PoleRow & ":$CH$" & PoleRow & ")"
Cells(PoleRow, 5).Formula = "=D" & PoleRow & "-3.33"
Range(Cells(PoleRow, 3), Cells(PoleRow, 5)).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
Range(Cells(PoleRow, 3), Cells(PoleRow, 5)).Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick
```

Comment: `If cell.Value = 0 Then cell.Clear` will do the Trick

Comment: Wrap your MIN formula like this:  `=IFERROR(1/1/MIN(...),"")`

Comment: You can use a custom number format to hide the value when equal to 0, for example `NumberFormat = "General;General;"`

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest strongly against to use the `cell` as they are already defined object in Excel. Use instead `cel` or `cl` or something similar for naming.

**In your case**

```
For Each cel In Range("D4:D400")
    If cel.Value = 0 Then cel.Clear
Next
```

will work. Or you can just use the Excel Function `IfError`

```
=IfError(1/1/(Your Formula), "") 'Courtesy Scott Craner
```

Or Use If Condition

```
 =IF(Your Formula <> 0, Your Formula, "")
```

---

**Code:**

```
If Evaluate("=MIN($AK$" & PoleRow & ":$CH$" & PoleRow & ")") = 0 Then
    Cells(PoleRow, 4) = ""
    Cells(PoleRow, 5) = "-3.33"
Else
    Cells(PoleRow, 4).formula = "=MIN($AK$" & PoleRow & ":$CH$" & PoleRow & ")"
    Cells(PoleRow, 5).formula = "=D" & PoleRow & "-3.33"
End If

Range(Cells(PoleRow, 3), Cells(PoleRow, 5)).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
Range(Cells(PoleRow, 3), Cells(PoleRow, 5)).Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick
```

Comment: Cells(PoleRow, 4).Formula = "=IFERROR(1/1/MIN($AK$" & PoleRow & ":$CH$" & PoleRow & "), "")"    This is what I have and says that theres is an application defined or object defined error

Comment: Try `Cells(PoleRow, 4).formula = "=IFERROR(1/1/MIN($AK$" & PoleRow & ":$CH$" & PoleRow & "), """")"`    ...........@bear21

Comment: That got rid of the 0's but it screwed up some of the values not equal to 0 at the same time:(   i edited my original post with what I am seeing after running that new formula named "edit". thanks!

Comment: From the results in your edit, you missed the two `1/` in the formula: it's `1/1/Min(...`

Comment: Cells(PoleRow, 4).Formula = "=IFERROR(1/1/MIN($AK$" & PoleRow & ":$CH$" & PoleRow & "), """")"    This is the line that was used in the edit screenshot

Comment: @bear21 .. Can you also paste the Original formula you used in the beginning ?

Comment: An I think the reason other formulas are messed up because they might be using values from the cells. When now it is blank, they are throwing error. You should post the complete code or maybe check yourself first, other formulas must be using the value from these cells

Comment: @Mikku I edited my original post with the complete code. Thanks!

Comment: @bear21 .. Try the Edited Code

Comment: @bear21 ... if it worked , then accept the answer :)